# How to calculate probabilities for a three pool elimination mechanic?

Tags: statistics, anydice

I've been struggling to get my head around this dice pool mechanic either in [anydice](http://www.anydice.com/) or even a bespoke program.

There are 3 pools of d6, call them A, B & C:

```
A: ad6
B: bd6 
C: cd6
```

Any dice in pools A and B that match any dice in pool C are removed from their respective pool.

The score is the highest non-eliminated dice in pool A or B (+0.1 if more than 1) **and** we need to know the total number of dice (not their values) of non-eliminated dice in pool B.

For example:

```
A: 3d6
B: 2d6
C: 4d6

Example 1
A: {6,2,6}  -> {6,2,6}
B: {2,1}    -> {2,1} 
C: {3,3,5,4}
Result: 6.1,2

Example 2
A: {5,1,6}  -> {5,x,x}
B: {1,4}    -> {x,x}
C: {1,6,6,4}
Result: 5,0

Example 3
A: {3,2,6}  -> {3,x,6}
B: {5,4}    -> {5,x}
C: {4,1,4,2}
Result: 6,1

Example 4
A: {6,5,5}  -> {x,5,5}
B: {1,4}    -> {x,4}
C: {6,3,1,3}
Result: 5.1,1
```

The mechanic is from [Technoir](http://www.technoirrpg.com/).

How do I model this?

Comment: I've [created a chat room for working out a solution to this conundrum](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26877/technoir-dice-calculations) where you might have an easier time talking about this (+ dumping code, writing a whole lot, etc) without the constraints comments impose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not (yet) exactly what you're asking for, but [here's an AnyDice program](http://anydice.com/program/65d7) that returns the highest roll in a dice pool, excluding any dice rolled in another pool:

```
function: highest of DICE:d excluding EXCL:s {
  NEW: {}
  loop I over {1@DICE} {
    if I = EXCL { I: 0 }
    NEW: {NEW, I}
  }
  POOL: (#DICE) d NEW
  result: 1@POOL
}
output [highest of 3d6 excluding 4d6]
```

It uses some pretty tricky AnyDice syntax, so let me explain a few of the details:

- When you pass a die to an AnyDice function expecting a sequence (like `EXCL:s` above), AnyDice will run the function for *every possible roll of the dice*, and sum the results (weighted by the probability of each roll).  This is basically a brute force approach, and it can easily time out for large dice pools, but it's very versatile when it works.  This is how I'm handling the exclusion mechanic here.
- `#DICE` gives the number of dice in the pool `DICE`, and `{1@DICE}` gives the possible values of a single die in the pool.  That is, if `DICE` = `3d6`, then `#DICE` = `3` and `{1@DICE}` = `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`.
- When you compare a number to a sequence (as in `I = EXCL`), the result will be true (non-zero) if the comparison is true for any element of the sequence.  That is, `if I = EXCL` basically checks whether `I` belongs to the sequence `EXCL`.

So what the loop inside the function does is construct a *custom die* `NEW` which looks just like one of the dice in `DICE`, but with any sides matching `EXCL` replaced by 0.  Then `POOL: (#DICE) d NEW` creates a new custom dice pool consisting of as many of those custom dice as there were in the original pool `DICE`, and the final line returns the highest result in that pool.

---

Getting a bit closer, here's [a version that adds the bonus for multiple equal highest dice](http://anydice.com/program/65db):

```
function: highest of ROLL:s with bonus {
  MAX: 1@ROLL
  BONUS: MAX > 0 & (MAX = ROLL) > 1
  result: 10 * MAX + BONUS
}
function: highest of DICE:d excluding EXCL:s {
  NEW: {}
  loop I over {1@DICE} {
    if I = EXCL { I: 0 }
    NEW: {NEW, I}
  }
  POOL: (#DICE) d NEW
  result: [highest of POOL with bonus]
}
output [highest of 3d6 excluding 4d6]
```

Since AnyDice doesn't support fractional numbers, I'm multiplying the result of the roll by 10, so that, say, a result of 5.1 (= 5 + 0.1 bonus) is represented as 51.

The code above is exactly the same as the first program above, except that I've replace `1@POOL` with a call to a helper function that adds the bonus if the highest roll occurs multiple times (and is not zero).  The helper function uses the same trick of taking the roll in as a sequence with `:s`, so that it gets automatically iterated over every possible outcome of the roll.

---

Finally, here's a program that [calculates the number of non-excluded dice](http://anydice.com/program/65d9) in pool B:

```
function: number of DICE:d excluding EXCL:s {
  NEW: {}
  loop I over {1@DICE} {
    NEW: {NEW, !(I = EXCL)}
  }
  result: (#DICE) d NEW
}
output [number of 2d6 excluding 4d6]
```

It's the same as the first program, except that now we're labeling the sides of our custom dice with 0 if they're in the exclusion list, and 1 otherwise, and then taking the sum of the roll as the result.

The remaining problem is to combine these programs, to account for the fact that both pools A and B depend on pool C simultaneously.  The problem is that AnyDice doesn't really handle two-dimensional output well, but we can use the same trick as we used to handle the 0.1 bonus above, multiplying the result of pool A further by 10 before adding the result of pool B, [like this](http://anydice.com/program/65dc):

```
function: highest of ROLL:s with bonus {
  MAX: 1@ROLL
  BONUS: MAX > 0 & (MAX = ROLL) > 1
  result: 10 * MAX + BONUS
}
function: highest of A:d and count of B:d excluding EXCL:s {
  ANEW: {}
  loop I over {1@A} {
    if I = EXCL { I: 0 }
    ANEW: {ANEW, I}
  }
  BNEW: {}
  loop I over {1@B} {
    BNEW: {BNEW, !(I = EXCL)}
  }
  result: 10 * [highest of (#A) d ANEW with bonus] + (#B) d BNEW
}
output [highest of 3d6 and count of 2d6 excluding 4d6] named "A.A, B"
```

Here, the output consists of a three-digit number `PQR`, where `P` is the highest non-excluded roll in pool A, `Q` is 1 if the highest non-excluded roll in pool A is multiple, and `R` is the number of non-excluded rolls in pool B.

---

Oh, wait! You said you wanted the highest roll in pools A and B *together*, not just the highest roll in A?  Well, [I can do that, too](http://anydice.com/program/65de), although it does require a little bit of reorganization, since the highest roll is no longer independent of the number of non-excluded rolls in pool B:

```
function: highest of A:s and B:s with bonus and count {
  MAX: [highest of 1@A and 1@B]
  BONUS: MAX > 0 & (MAX = A) + (MAX = B) > 1
  COUNT: B > 0
  result: 100 * MAX + 10 * BONUS + COUNT
}
function: SEQ:s excluding EXCL:s {
  NEW: {}
  loop I over SEQ {
    if I = EXCL { I: 0 }
    NEW: {NEW, I}
  }
  result: NEW
}
function: highest of A:d and B:d with bonus and count excluding EXCL:s {
  AX: (#A) d [{1@A} excluding EXCL]
  BX: (#B) d [{1@B} excluding EXCL]
  result: [highest of AX and BX with bonus and count]
}
output [highest of 3d6 and 2d6 with bonus and count excluding 4d6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Anydice [doesn't actually roll any dice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/57714/23852), so you can't create the pools (unless I am wrong)
but once you have the pools [this](http://anydice.com/program/65d5) may be what you need.

You will need to enter manually A,B and C (on the top) and then calculate, select "Roller" and roll the two outputs.

PS : there is not 0.1 in Anydice so if the number is present twice it add 100 instead.

```
//the pools for the results of your dices
A:{6,5,5}
B:{1,4}
C:{6,3,1,3}

//a simple function returning the greater of 2 numbers
function: maxi A and B {
 if A>B {
  result:A
 }
 else {
  result:B
 }
}

//creation of the two maximums initialized at -1 to be sure it doesn't overlap 
//(0 is fine too)
MAXA:-1
MAXB:-1

//counters, number_of_time_maximum_seen -1
TWICEA:0
TWICEB:0

//#A stand for the size of A
//the first loop, go from 1 to the size of A (first pool)
loop P over {1..#A}
{
 //P@A stand for the P-th value of A
 if !(P@A = C) {
  //if the P-th value of A is inside C (last pool), check if this maximum has been seen or not and take the appropriate action
  if MAXA = P@A {
   TWICEA : 1 + TWICEA
  }
  else {
   MAXA : [maxi MAXA and P@A]
   TWICEA: 0
  }
 }
}

//the number of dice in B not in C
COUNT:#B
loop P over {1..#B} 
{
 if (P@B = C){
  //if the P-th value of B is in C the count decrease by 1
  COUNT : COUNT - 1
 }
 //if the P-th value of B isn't in C the same thing as A (see A loop)
 else {
 if MAXB = P@B {
   TWICEB: 1 + TWICEB
  }
  else {
   MAXB : [maxi MAXB and P@B]
   TWICEB: 0
  }
 }

 //if the two maximum are equals the highest is the one seen the more
 if (MAXA = MAXB) {
  output MAXA + 100 * ([maxi TWICEA and TWICEB]!=0)
 }
 //if the maximums are not equals the greater win
 else if (MAXA >MAXB) {
  output MAXA+100*(TWICEA!=0) named "highest non-eliminated dice"
 }
 else {
  output MAXB+100*(TWICEB!=0) named "highest non-eliminated dice"
 }
}
output COUNT named "non-eliminated dice count in pool B".
```

Answer (score 0):

### Faster solution than AnyDice

Unfortunately, even with pre-filtering the outcomes before computing the Action (A) and Push (B) pools, AnyDice times out if an additional die is added to either of these pools. Here's a [JupyterLite notebook](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/notebooks/lab?path=technoir.ipynb) based on my Icepool Python package that can compute the solution more quickly. You can edit the code and run it right in your browser.

```
import icepool
from icepool import d6

# An MultisetEvaluator incrementally computes the result
# given how many dice in each pool rolled each outcome.
class EvalTechnoir(icepool.MultisetEvaluator):
    def next_state(self, state, outcome, action, push, hurt):
        if state is None:
            # Initial state.
            highest, multiple_highest, surviving_push = 0, False, 0
        else:
            highest, multiple_highest, surviving_push = state
        # If this number is not cancelled...
        if hurt == 0:
            total = action + push
            if total > 0:
                # Outcomes are seen in ascending order by default,
                # so a new outcome is always the highest.
                highest = outcome
                multiple_highest = total > 1
                surviving_push += push
        return highest, multiple_highest, surviving_push

eval_technoir = EvalTechnoir()

# 3d6 Action, 2d6 Push, 4d6 Hurt.
# The outcomes are the highest surviving die,
# whether more than one die rolled the highest number,
# and the number of surviving Push dice (of any outcome).
print(eval_technoir(d6.pool(3), d6.pool(2), d6.pool(4)))
```

#### Algorithm

[Here's a paper](https://github.com/HighDiceRoller/icepool/blob/main/papers/icepool_preprint.pdf) of the algorithm to speed up pool computations. This avoids the exhaustive enumeration used by AnyDice's pool-to-sequence conversion, though in this case the unusual number of pools does decrease the advantage.